# Where Kafka fits in a traditional 3-tier app

Tags: apache-kafka

I recently started learning apache kafka. After getting some initial idea i am at the point where i am confused about where kafka fits in app architecture.

I mean how do we introduce it in to the simple app which previously has only three layers. Frontend (Android app), backend (Node.js), MySQL. User can create a post from app , app will call endpoint on node.js and it will store the post in db.

In this simple, straight forward architecture what additional things will kafka add ? How it will be integrated?

Comment: It's a wrong approach to try to push kafka into existing systems without a need. There might be a good reasons to do it and good reasons to don't. Depends on the architecture.

Comment: You can use Kafka for Database replication.

Comment: You don' need it until you do, and when you do you might be better off using something much simpler than Kafka. Don't put the cart before the horse. What's your use-case?

Comment: Kafka (and other Middleware) is more likely useful at a distributed enterprise level, rather than trying to stuff it into a '3 tier app'. Kafka's throughput has use in high volume event driven systems (e.g. IoT), its efficient persistence and pub sub capabilities have many use cases including big data, streaming, and rules engines, and the consistent hash partitioning allow for horizontal scaling of stateful services like actor model. If you don't need one of these use cases you don't need a distributed log like Kafka.

Comment: @Evert i am not specifically learning kafka with use case in mind. Currently i am exploring kafka and trying to understand where it is used.

Comment: IMHO Kafka's main uses case is to decouple a producer from one or more consumer(s). We used kafka for exactly this use case. Using kafka the producer simply publishes/produces messages to a kafka topic and doesn't have to keep track of all the consumers

Answer (score 0):

Let's give an example - database upgrades that require downtime.

What happens if your NodeJS application cannot connect to the database during this period but **can** successfully write to Kafka? (You'd rewrite your Node app to write to Kafka instead of the database.)

In that case, Kafka acts as a buffer while you do database maintenance.

---

This is just one example, but you could also consume your Kafka topic into both MySQL and Elasticsearch (or other database) to support other use-cases like search-faceting or log analysis. You wouldn't need to edit any upstream Node code to write to multiple downstream systems except to publish multiple event types to Kafka.